# Create mini loop in the head to use advanced excerpt - loop to use current post ID

Tags: wordpress

I am using [advanced excerpt](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-excerpt/) plugin because there is so much more flexibility with it's options.

Though if found a drawback with the plugin, I have to remove the standard excerpt function using `remove_all_filters('the_excerpt');` other wise it conflicts with the advanced excerpt options.

**Problem**

I want to add the except to my head in a open graph meta for facebook. Usually I would do this with a simple `get_the_excerpt();` and weave this into the meta tag like so...

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>" />
```

But this will not work - because I have removed the excerpt filter.

**How to fix?**

My attempt below creating WP query which gets the current ID and creates a mini loop where I can place the the advance expert call in.

But for some reason this loop breaks my site, and I cant seem to fix. Can anyone please help me fix this loop. Would very much appreciate it thanks.

```
<?php if ( is_single() || is_page() ) {

    $postID         = get_the_ID();
    $fbexcerpt      = new WP_Query(array( 'p' => $postID ));

    while ($fbexcerpt->have_posts()) :
    $fbexcerpt->the_post();

    echo '<meta property="og:description" content="' . the_advanced_excerpt('length=120&use_words=0') . '" />';

    unset($fbexcerpt);
    endif; wp_reset_query();

} ?>
```

---

**UPDATE**

If anyone has any alternative ideas that does not require 'advanced excerpt' - Then I am inserting the open graph meta via my functions.php

```
function insert_fb_in_head() {
    global $post;
    if ( !is_singular()) 
        return;

        echo '<meta property="og:description" content=" . $MyExcerptHere . "/>';

    echo "\n";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'insert_fb_in_head', 5 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use [get_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) ?

```
 $my_post = get_post($id);
 $excerpt = $my_post->post_excerpt;
```

Then use a function like this to retrieve words up to x characters:

```
  function extractText150char($text, $length = '150') {
    $textArr = explode(' ', $text);
    $text = '';

    // Loop through each word
    for ( $i=0; $i<count($textArr)-1; $i++ ) {
      $text .= $textArr[$i] . ' ';
      // Check string length
      if ( (strlen($text) + strlen($textArr[$i+1]) ) > $length )
        return $text;
    }
    return $text;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Steven for you idea but I can't get it return anything. Let's say I use your idea as a function... But it returns nothing..
`
function insert_fb_in_head() {
 global $post;
 if ( !is_singular()) 
  return;

        $my_post = get_post($id);
        $excerpt = $my_post->post_excerpt;       
        echo '<meta property="og:description" content="' . $excerpt . '"/>';

 echo "\n";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'insert_fb_in_head', 5 );
`

Comment: Do you get any output if you do `var_dump($my_post)`? If yes, do you get any output if you do `echo $my_post->post_excerpt`? If yes, then `extractText150char()` should work. If not, just modify it to return the length of your string.